# Prevent Windows firing events during long touch of a button

Tags: c#, winforms, events, touch, touchscreen

WinForms application.
User touches a button (touchscreen) that causes authentication and the screen (A) is changed to another screen (B). If user continues to hold the finger on the screen (just for a second) the screen B has a button that overlaps with the button on screen (A) and the button on screen B inadvertently gets a touch and invokes an action that is not supposed to happen...

How do I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: But if the user is holding the button on screen A, the click will never fire unless the user lets go of the button. Is that not the case for you?

Comment: nope, the user touches the screen and does not let go - the form changes to another (UserControl) that has another button exactly at that place where user still touches - and this generates "touch/click" on that other button...

Comment: What is the event that is causing this: in code is it a button's clck event or some other event?

Comment: On screen A when button clicked i have button_Clicked event handler...

Answer (score 0):

That is weird behavior. I do not have a touch device to test this but in a regular scenario the `click` only triggers when the button is pressed and then released while the button is still in focus. If you press the button and do not release, the `click` event will not fire.

Anyhow perhaps what you can do is only show screen B when the button has been pressed and then it has lost focus. Like this:

```
private bool buttonIsClicked = false;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.buttonIsClicked = true;

}
private void button1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.buttonIsClicked)
    {
        this.buttonIsClicked = !this.buttonIsClicked;
        // show screen B
    }
}
```

Please use a variable like I have used `buttonIsClicked` so the code in `Leave` event handler is not executed every time the button loses focus even if it is not clicked.

Comment: I will try that - I also was thinking about something like that - the problem is that I dont have touch screen either - and am basing on report from my client. 
Also I found this on MS site: Tap the screen and hold until the mouse icon appears and disappears. Users are likely to do this when they accident-tally press and hold and want to revert to just tap.
ISG_TAP sent when pen is lifted.
Actually I will not be able to do what you suggested: The click on screen A leads to a series of events and handlers and screen B shows up only upon success of particular response from web servince...